# hg rebase abort fails: "unknown revision"

Tags: mercurial, mercurialeclipse

Occasionally when performing a rebase using the MercurialEclipse plugin my repository gets thrown into an odd state.   It will become stuck in a "rebasing" state, yet when I try to abort the rebase (e.g. "hg rebase -a") I get this error message:

> abort: unknown revision '*xxxx*'!

Where xxxx is a revision hash. Usually at this point I've abandoned all hope of performing the rebase -- I just want to get back to a happier time when my repository was not screwed up.  So far my solution has been to nuke my project directory and clone it again. Is there a less drastic solution?

Comment: I can confirm the issue still exists, this was discussed on the lists: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.devel/36295 but no fix is still in

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just remove the .hg/rebasestate and your repo will work.

The patch described in [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.devel/36296) thread calls the internal function clearstate which just unlinks this file.

Comment: Hah, it worked!   Thanks also for finding the issue on the hg devlist. Perhaps we can revisit this answer once the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In situations similar to this, I usually do:

```
$ hg check
$ hg verify
$ hg up -C default
```

Instead of `default`, use whatever branch you're working on. This takes time, but so does re-cloning the repo.

It usually helps.